# Listing manufacturers on home.tpl

Tags: php, opencart

In my main page im retrieving the list of categories using just:

```
$results = $this->model_catalog_category->getCategories();
```

Using the same logic to retrieve the manufacturers list:

```
$results = $this->model_catalog_manufacturer->getManufacturers();
```

But this time I get an error:

> Fatal error: Call to a member function getManufacturers() on a
>   non-object in
>   C:\wamp\www\ecommerce\catalog\view\theme\pinshop\template\common\home.tpl

So I guess in home.tpl the contant `model_catalog_manufacturer` is not defined, Am I right? How can I solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to load the manufacturer model before you can use the method

```
$this->load->model('catalog/manufacturer');
```

Once you add that before the `$results = ...` line above, it will work